# How do I move a gameobject through a series of coordinates that are stored in an array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

So I have a gameObject which is the player and a raycast determines which point the player has to move to. It's basically a controlled jump. I calculate a bezier curve from player position to the raycast point and I store the points of those bezier cure in an array. I need the player object to move through those points.
This is what I have so far but the movement is choppy and not smooth.

```
    private IEnumerator Jump()
{
    
    Debug.Log("Turned Jump");

    foreach (Vector3 item in positions)
    {
        isMoving = true;

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, item, Time.deltaTime * 100000f);
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }

    isMoving = false;
    jumpCheck = false;

   
    
    yield return null;
    if(isMoving)  checkJumpBlock() ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 answers. One of them is that you don't have to use a Bezier curve. if you want to use a curve you can use a simple for-each loop

```
foreach(Vector3 v in positions) {
   transform.position = v;
   yeild return new waitForEndOfFrame();
}
```

otherwise just use a Rigidbody and add a force to the transform.up